# Firebase sign in with email and password verification fails with correct credentials

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase sign-in with email & password fails with correct credentials
I've followed these instructions: [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth)

1. I have added user manually
2. I have enabled Sign in with Email & Password
3. I have also enabled OAuth
4. I also have correct email format & password > 8 characters

Here is the code:

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener(this,new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                {
                  if(!task.isSuccessful())
                  {

                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }

                }
            });
```

**UPDATE:**
If i run app on mobile device it works fine but doesnt work in emulator

Comment: please logcat the whole value of returned task and print it here ! so we can see the solution

Comment: can you please tell how to do that?

Comment: log.d("incomingResult",task.toString());  put this in OnComplete method

Comment: 05-04 13:28:05.165 2208-2208/com.mustahsanmustafa.firebase D/MainActivity: com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn@17c8b141

Comment: the only thing I see  that you are missing is might the be the RULES of firebase for this! did you check that?

Comment: i have configured all rules available in firebase dashboard

Comment: can you please show the rules of yours!

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Comment: can you please post how you get email and password from above in order to send it to firebase? thanks

Comment: I added it manually from firebase console web